# Are review audits turned off on our site, or did I just ace all of them without noticing?

Tags: discussion

Today I learned about a new Stack Exchange concept, called **Review Audits** (for more information, please see [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)).

Well, after having reviewed a fair amount of posts on our site (600+), I was quite surprised to learn about the new concept, and, more importantly, that I was being tested (yes, I'm a bit paranoid). I never came across an audit, at least, not that I know of. So, my questions are:

- Since I've never seen any audits here, **are review audits turned off for our site?**
- Have I been audited but didn't notice?
- Have I aced all the audits without noticing any of them? (not likely, but possible)
- Have I failed a bunch of them, and now should wait for the Review Police to knock on my door?

When I think I've seen everything that could ever be invented in StackExchange... then I learn about some more.

Comment: Be glad they're turned off, I've only ever failed two or three overall (so never had a review ban) on Stack Overflow but some of them really suck. They can include questions asked years ago that have never had close / downvotes that look like they are new questions. Some of them would be downvoted and closed within minutes if asked today but you fail them even for a downvote when they don't meet current guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these are currently only active on the three big sites, as per [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work#comment520523_157121) on the question you linked to. Actually, that is the post that I would take all my information from.

If they were active, you would know immediately after completing a review test whether it was an audit or not.